# selecting subset of matrix based on condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix

```
test = [1 2 3 4;
        2 3 4 5;
        3 4 5 6;
        4 5 6 7;
        5 6 7 8];
```

I would like to select the **rows** whose first entry has a value between 1 and 3. I tried with

```
test(test(:,1)<3 && test(:,1)>1)
```

but that gave me an error. Then I tried with

```
test(1<test(:,1)<3)
```

but that doesn't give me the desired result `2 3 4 5`. Is there a way to obtain this is Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I couldn't test it in Matlab but it should work.

```
test((1 < test(:,1) && test(:,1) < 3),:)
```

Explanation:

This
    (1 < test(:,1) && test(:,1) < 3)
Get's a binary array with the rows that fit the criteria, then you use that to select the rows.

See [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In order to logically compare vectors one by one you have to use & instead of &&:

```
test(test(:,1)<3 & test(:,1)>1,:)
```

This produces the answer:

```
 2     3     4     5
```

Comment: I tested this in Matlab.