# 2D contour plot with extracted data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data set on the form of 3 spatial coordinates `x,y,z` and an amplitude, here is a small crop of the data:

```
[        0    2.9373    0.4646    2.9926
    0.8384    1.5338    1.0000    1.0016
         0    0.7619    0.5051    1.0033
    1.0000    3.5288    0.6667    2.9894
         0    0.5013    0.4343    1.0037
    1.0000    2.8070    0.4848    2.9935
    0.7980    4.0000    0.8586    2.9872
    1.0000    0.1404    0.0707    1.0043
    1.0000    1.7845    0.1818    1.0007
    0.9798    3.1679    1.0000    2.9913]
```

What I would like is a 2D contour plot, where the interface is represented by the contour levels within, say, 2.0 +/- 0.05.

First I start by making the data 2D and thus choose the values `z` within +/- 0.01. Then I am only left with `x,y,amplitude`.

Then I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394519/selecting-subset-of-matrix-based-on-condition) for extracting the data sets that satisfy `data(:,4)` is within 2.0 +/- 0.05.

However, what remains now is actually making the contour plot. I tried `contour` but that requires the data to have a format of `meshgrid`, which it does not. So my question is, what is the easiest way to make a contour plot of the extracted data?

Comment: I posted an answer but realized it won't work. Contour is meant for 2D data only. You will have to do something like use the `isosurface` function. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684023/how-to-plot-4d-contour-lines-xyz-v-in-matlab).

Comment: @BrianLynch Thanks. I reformulated my question to be applicable to 2D as well, would like to hear your suggestions

Comment: That is much easier to solve, I edited my answer but didn't check it thoroughly yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an interpolation function for your scattered data like this:

```
F_interp = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,amplitude);
```

Then setup a gridded mesh of interpolation points (using limits and sizes that could be based on the original data):

```
xMin = min(x);
xMax = max(x);
yMin = min(y);
yMax = max(y);
Nx = 2*length(x);
Ny = 2*length(y);
xpts = linspace(xMin,xMax,Nx);
ypts = linspace(yMin,yMax,Ny);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xpts,ypts);
```

Interpolate the data at those gridded points:

```
A = F_interp(X,Y);
```

Now pass the interpolated data to the MATLAB `contour` function:

```
contour(X,Y,A);
```